# failed to create component 'reportviewer'. the error message follows 'system.runtime.interopservices.comexception' vs 2015

Tags: c#

I have tried resetting toolbox and i updated 'microsoft.reporting.winforms' packages to v11 but still same error occurs.
Failed to create component 'ReportViewer'. The error message follows 'System.Runtime.Interopservices.COMexception'.A reference to the component 'microsoft.reporting.winforms' already exists in the project.

Comment: please share us your code, so we will be able to help you

Comment: I had a problem on using toolbox report viewer control in win forms.Changing the version of reference to reporting.winforms to 12.0.0.0,it worked fine for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a reference to microsoft.reporting.winforms version 10.0.0.0   . I removed it from reference and downloaded report viewer for visual studio 2015.Then,I added a reference to microsoft.reporting.winforms version 12.0.0.0 .I was able to use the report viewer. Hopefully,it works.

Comment: Similar solution but with a little different detail: I had an error of `C1.Win.C1Command 4.5.2`, but that is the only one in my reference list. So I remove it and add it again. Then problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using VS2017 v15.9.21 and I had to develop some changes in an old project .NET Framework 4.5.2 
I was following the instructions in this post: 
[Integrating Reporting Services Using the Report Viewer Controls - Get Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver15#adding-control-to-visual-studio-toolbar)

But it gives me an error when I was trying to add the Report Viewer Control from the toolbox. 
I was executing the nuget command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
```

And the VS keeps throwing me this error failing to create the component because of some assembly from the last version
`Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1404.0`:

[image: Failed to create component 'Report Viewer']

So I decided to downgrade the version to the last 140 version number

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 140.1000.523
```

And voilà! 
Works like a charm.

[image: Report viewer control in windows form]

Answer (score 3):

Just remove microsoft.reporting.winforms from the reference. It works for me. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As I am using RDLC report in desktop application. so I just removed `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms` nuget package. I have install it by mistake and install the alternative packages. `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms` for windows application works for me, but I'm using two more package with it:

```
Corrected.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.v12
```

Answer (score 1):

Locate solution explorer from your visual studio, from under the references section right click and remove any file relating to crystal reports then you can go on to the tool box and add in crystal report viewer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved by install `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms` from  Manage NuGet Packages