# how to fix this problem in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

[this is the error that appears once i try to drag a crystal report viewer to a form in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Er4p.png)

I'm facing an error when i try to add a crystal report viewer in a form in visual studio, I am using visual basic in my desktop application.
it just keeps showing me these message in the picture.
any one can help me with this issue?

here is the message bellow:

```
Failed to create component 'CrystalReportViewer'. The error message follows:
'System.Runtime .lnteropServices.COMException  {Ox8004D745):
A reference to the component
'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Form s' already exists in the project. at VSLangProj.References .Add{String  bstrPath)
at
Microsoft.Visu alStud io.Design.VSTypeReso lutionService.Perfor mReferenceUpd ate{list'l  newReferences)
at
Microsoft.Visu alStud io.Design.VSTypeReso lutionService.Syste m.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeReso lutionService.Reference Assembly(AssemblyName name)
at
Microsoft.Visu alStud io.Design.Serialization.CodeDom .Aggreg ateTypeResolutionService.Reference   Assembly(AssemblyName
name)
at
System.Drawing.Design.Toolboxltem     .GetType{IDesignerHost host,AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName,
Boolean reference)
at
System.Drawing.Design.Toolboxltem .CreateComponentsCore {I DesignerHost host)
at
System.Drawing.Design.Toolboxltem .CreateComponentsCore {I DesignerHost host, !Dictionary defaultValues)
at
System.Drawing.Design.Toolboxltem .CreateComponents {IDesi gnerHost host, !Dictionary defaultValues)
at Sy...'
```

Comment: Please copy the text over so that other that will run into the same problem will be able to find it.

Comment: okay, i did add the message

Comment: You may want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529104/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows-system-run) and see if it helps you solve this problem.  Its a very similar error to yours.

Comment: okay I'll check it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem I found that the solution is to go to your project references and delete the extensions in the following picture

[image: crystal report extensions]