# Crystal Report and RDLC report returns error:"failed to create component 'reportviewer'.the error message follows microsoft.dotnet.design

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

i have already tried updating the NuGet packages also done my research on the internet tried these step mentioned here:
https://codeinpocket.com/how-to-enable-report-viewer-in-visual-studio-2022/

also this:
[failed to create component 'reportviewer'. the error message follows 'system.runtime.interopservices.comexception' vs 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529104/failed-to-create-component-reportviewer-the-error-message-follows-system-run)

still I am not able to solve the issue what I am missing here is the picture of error
[image: error details]

I was using crystal reports earlier in vs 2019 which is also not supported in vs 2022 so can someone actually guide me how to print POS Receipts easily and simply.

Comment: Dot net version?

Comment: i am using .net 6.0

Comment: As per my knowledge only dot net 4.8 support Report Viewer Tool, Microsoft ended support for Report Viewer tool in dot net core and dot net 5 and on-wards,

Comment: What's the solution do we need to use printdocment for POS receipts or how to make receipt printing ?

Comment: my question is still pending that how can we make RDLC or Crystal Report work in Dot net 6.0 or higher can someone explains it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small demo project to print receipt using System.Drawings

https://github.com/mwaqasaziz/ReceiptPrintingWithSystemDrawing

Answer (score 0):

well unfortunately there is currently no support for Crystal Report or RDLC at the moment, Crystal Report support dotnet framework 4.8 for now there is no solution for Reporting service to work with application written in dotcore framework.

There is no Reporting service supported at the moment for dot core framework so you can wait for Microsoft to make support for COM services or Crystal Report to Adopt Dotcore for reporting or you can use PRINTDOCUMENT service and make receipt with totally manual code.

if someone still want detailed info about this issue you can have a look on this article here:

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13029137/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-and-net-core-5-a.html

best solution for now is to Add a new project in same solution with "dotnet framework 4.8 windows Forms" add "Project reference" to your current project to the new dotnet 4.8 project create Crystal report or others there and you are all good to go